# `method_missing': undefined method `user_class=' for #<Forem::Engine:0x9de6bc0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, method-missing, forem

When i run rails server,i encountered this error.
'bundle install' has been success.My RVM use ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2 but the project need rails 3.1.I think the bundle has already solved the because of the bundle.The rails and ruby might not be the reason.
Anything would be help.Thanks
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle

```
magic@magic-ThinkPad-T430u:~/Documents/rails/ticketee-book$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0.rc2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `user_class=' for #<Forem::Engine:0x9de6bc0> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/config/initializers/forem.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:641:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:544:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `each'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:641:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /home/magic/Documents/rails/ticketee-book/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-623c16f4f8b7/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running server with `bundle` command. It will use all gems that are defined in your `Gemfile` then:

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Comment: Do you have `gem 'forem'` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: no.That line contains 'forem' in the Gemfile has been commented off.The 'vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems' dir does not contain it.But the 'vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems' contains a folder named 'forem-6b2a1de9113e'.Does this be the reason?

Comment: That looks like the reason. You have commented out the `forem` gem in your Gemfile but you are requiring it in your initializer `config/initializers/forem.rb`. Bring back `gem 'forem'` to your `Gemfile` and see what happens.

Comment: When i bring back the 'forem',i got the following error: `Updating git://github.com/radar/forem
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    forem (>= 0) ruby depends on
rails (!= 3.2.0, != 3.2.1, != 3.2.10, != 3.2.2, != 3.2.3, != 3.2.4, !=
3.2.5, != 3.2.6, != 3.2.7, != 3.2.8, != 3.2.9, < 3.3, >= 3.1.10) ruby

    rails (3.1.0.rc2)`